# Marking a class as "safe" for rendering in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm writing a class that will be returned by a custom template filter. It has a `__str__` method that returns HTML. I don't want that HTML to be escaped.

I've tried just calling `mark_safe` on my string before returning it from the `__str__` method, but the result is escaped. I'm assuming this is because Django is checking if the object is safe before converting it to a string?

Can I somehow mark the class itself as safe?

e.g.

```
class ParagraphTag(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return mark_safe('<p>{}</p>'.format(self.text + 'baz'))

@register.filter(name='paragraph_tag')
def paragraph_tag(text):
    return ParagraphTag(text)
```

Rendering a paragraph tag object in a template then results in it being escaped.

e.g. `{{ paragraph_tag }}` -> `<p>foo</p>`

If I call `mark_safe` on the `ParagraphTag` object itself when returning it from my template filter, then it gets turned into a `SafeBytes` object which is not what I want. I want to have the rich object available in my template and only have it converted to a string when rendered.

Comment: can you not return safe from the template filter? It would help if you could show an example snippet of code.

Comment: @Sayse added an example

Comment: In your first sentence you say that this class will be returned from a custom template filter, so do you have an example of that? it would make more sense (to me) to use safe in that. Otherwise, what problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @Sayse as I mentioned, if I try and mark my rich object as safe it gets turned into a `SafeBytes` object. My goal was to have an object of which I could interrogate individual attributes, for example as part of a `haschanged` block, but knows how to render itself as HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django generally uses `unicode()` to get a string out of Python objects. You have to implement `__unicode__` so that it returns a safe Unicode string. Otherwie, the default value that will be returned will be taken from `__str__` but will be made unsafe by the transformation.

For the record, here is the code I used to diagnose it:

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

class ParagraphTag(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return mark_safe('<p>{}</p>'.format(self.text + 'baz'))

print str(ParagraphTag("foo")).__class__
print str(ParagraphTag("foo"))
print 
print unicode(ParagraphTag("foo")).__class__
print unicode(ParagraphTag("foo"))
print mark_safe(unicode(ParagraphTag("foo"))).__class__
```

This will output:

```
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeBytes'>
<p>foobaz</p>

<type 'unicode'>
<p>foobaz</p>
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
```

And here is an example of a class that will produce safe Unicode:

```
class ParagraphTagFixed(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode("utf-8")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return mark_safe(u'<p>{}</p>'.format(self.text + u'baz'))

print unicode(ParagraphTagFixed("foo")).__class__
print unicode(ParagraphTagFixed("foo"))
print str(ParagraphTagFixed("foo")).__class__
print str(ParagraphTagFixed("foo"))
```

It will show:

```
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
<p>foobaz</p>
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeBytes'>
<p>foobaz</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that `__str__` should return a string. Yours does not, and that is what is causing you trouble.

Django rather uses `__html__` for escaped strings. In fact it provides an `html_safe` deecorator that creates this method based on your definition of `__str__`.

On Python 3, you can define your class like that:

```
from django.utils.html import html_safe

@html_safe
class Test():
    def __str__(self):
        return '<p>Hey</p>'
```

And on Python 2:

```
from django.utils.html import html_safe
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@html_safe
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Test():
    def __str__(self):
        return '<p>Hey</p>'
```

(or you can define `__unicode__` rather than `__str__`).